# Android: How to read data into a main activity

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to develop an app which in the main activity displays a list of users courses. This data is stored in SQLite. If the user wishes to add more courses they can do so through a button press to take them to a new activity. I have a database created however I am struggling where it comes to reading in the data. I've looked at much documentation but there seems to be various methods without any consistent implmentation. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Im trying to use a SimpleCursorAdapter to get get the data, put it into an int array and 
display the information in  listview.

Logcat

```
10-21 02:08:20.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7044): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
10-21 02:08:20.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7044): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mycoursetimetable/com.example.mycoursetimetable.MyCourses}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
10-21 02:08:20.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7044):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
10-21 02:08:20.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7044):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
10-21 02:08:20.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7044):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
10-21 02:08:20.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7044):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
10-21 02:08:20.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7044):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-21 02:08:20.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7044):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-21 02:08:20.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7044):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
10-21 02:08:20.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7044):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-21 02:08:20.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7044):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-21 02:08:20.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7044):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
10-21 02:08:20.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7044):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
10-21 02:08:20.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7044):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-21 02:08:20.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7044): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
10-21 02:08:20.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7044):     at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:234)
10-21 02:08:20.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7044):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:201)
10-21 02:08:20.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7044):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1622)
10-21 02:08:20.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7044):     at com.example.mycoursetimetable.MyCourses.onCreate(MyCourses.java:39)
10-21 02:08:20.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7044):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-21 02:08:20.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7044):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
10-21 02:08:20.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7044):     ... 11 more
10-21 02:08:20.082: I/dalvikvm(7044): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
10-21 02:08:20.082: E/dalvikvm(7044): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
10-21 02:08:22.082: I/Process(7044): Sending signal. PID: 7044 SIG: 9
```

activity_my_courses Layout

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/labelAddCourseButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="addCourseButton"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/CourseName" />

    <ListView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Main Activity

```
public class MyCourses extends ListActivity {

    static final String TEST = "com.example.mycoursetimetable.TEST";
    String [] MODULE;
    private database MODULEDATABASE;  
    ListView listContent;

    Cursor cursor;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_courses);

       listContent =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.contentlist);
       MODULEDATABASE = new database(this);

       cursor = MODULEDATABASE.getData();
       String [] from = new String[]{database.KEY_MODULECODE,database.KEY_MODULENAME};
```

int[] to = new int[] {R.id.labelModuleCode,  R.id.labelEditModuleFull};
           cursorAdapter CA = new  cursorAdapter(this,R.layout.listcourses, cursor, from, to, 0);

```
       listContent.setAdapter(CA);

        }

        class cursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

        private Context context;
        private int layout;

        public cursorAdapter(Context context,int layout, Cursor cursor,String [] from, int[] to, int flag)
        {
            super(context,layout, cursor, from, to, flag);
            this.context = context;
            this.layout = layout;
        }
```

}

Database Class

public class database {

```
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_MODULECODE = "module_code";
public static final String KEY_MODULENAME = "module_name";
public static final String KEY_MODULETYPE = "module_type";
public static final String KEY_MODULEDAY = "module_day";
public static final String KEY_MODULESTART = "module_start";
public static final String KEY_MODULEEND = "module_end";
public static final String KEY_MODULELOCATION = "module_location";
public static final String KEY_MODULECOMMENTS = "module_comments";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "module_database";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "my_modules";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper myHelper;
private final Context myContext;
private SQLiteDatabase moduleDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DbHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE +  " (" +
                    KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    KEY_MODULECODE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_MODULENAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_MODULELOCATION + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_MODULECOMMENTS + " TEXT NOT NULL); "
                );

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABEL IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

    }


}

public database(Context c){
    myContext = c;
}

public  database openToWrite()throws SQLException{
    myHelper = new DbHelper(myContext);
    moduleDatabase = myHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public  database openToRead()throws SQLException{
    myHelper = new DbHelper(myContext);
    moduleDatabase = myHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    return this;
}
public void close(){
myHelper.close();
}

public long createEntry(String moduleCode, String moduleName,  String moduleLocation, String moduleComments) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_MODULECODE,moduleCode);
    cv.put(KEY_MODULENAME,moduleName);
    cv.put(KEY_MODULELOCATION,moduleLocation);
    cv.put(KEY_MODULECOMMENTS,moduleComments);
    return moduleDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null,cv);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public Cursor getData() {

    String[] columns = new String [] {KEY_ROWID,KEY_MODULECODE, KEY_MODULENAME};
    Cursor c = moduleDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    return c;
}
```

}

Comment: Please be more specific, what exactly doesn't work for you? Did you learn any tutorials on the topic?

Comment: Currently Im getting a runtime error when I try to first launch the program. Sorry I'm trying to find the error, but the more I mess with it the more errors I'm getting.

Comment: LogCat Unable to find activity ComponentInfo?

Comment: Sorry Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Comment: make sure your AndroidManifest.xml is set up correctly, specifically if your activity is named correctly.

Comment: With an exception, always post the relevant logcat.

Comment: I think this what you mean, I'm unsure. 10-20 22:54:56.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1712): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
10-20 22:54:56.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1712): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mycoursetimetable/com.example.mycoursetimetable.MyCourses}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the issue is simply that you forgot to open your database before running the cursor. But i'm not sure that that's the *only* problem, 'cause you haven't put what errors you're receiving(please do next time), so i did a rewrite with an extension of the full `cursoradapter` rather than the simple one, in hopes that it is more straightforward and flexible in the future. It's just my preference, but i don't see why one would use the `SimpleCursorAdapter` over the more robust one if one was to extend it anyway. in your listactivity class:

```
    MODULEDATABASE = new database(this);
    MODULEDATABASE.openToRead(); // don't forget this part!
    cursor = MODULEDATABASE.getData();

    listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contentlist);
    TestCursorAdapter ca = new TestCursorAdapter(this, cursor, 0);
    listContent.setAdapter(ca);
```

And here is the adapter:

```
public class TestCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater viewInflater;

    public TestCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        viewInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {
        TextView text_modulecode = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.labelModuleCode);
        TextView text_modulename = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.labelEditModuleFull);

        text_modulecode.setText(c.getColumnIndex("module_code"));
        text_modulename.setText(c.getColumnIndex("module_name"));
//      ^ set above to your real column locations, if incorrect 
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = viewInflater.inflate(R.layout.listcourses, parent, false);
        return v;
    }

}
```

Moreover, i hope you don't forget that "TABLE" is spelt wrongly in:
`db.execSQL("DROP TABEL IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);` in your database class

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. I implmented the code above. but too no avail. I've added the Full logcat above. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: according to the stack trace, something is amiss at line 39 of the MyCourses `onCreate` method. it looks like you might be calling a linear-layout object, something else. if `listContent =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.contentlist);` is at line 39, make sure that `R.id.contentlist` refers to the listview and not something else. **BUT** you should know that if you're applying a listview to a `ListActivity` rather than regular activity, your listview id **MUST** be `"@id/android:list"` or you'll get another crash and another error.

Comment: Thanks for the direction, the error appears at setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_courses) which could be related to the id I set for the ListView. I altered the Ids to "@id/android:list" . How do you identify the listview in the code as R.id.list doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Actually ignore the above comment. It solved my layout error. Now I have an SQL error but I will try solve this now that I have a clearer picture. Thanks again.